# How to create WebDriverIO Browser Instances in afterCommand hooks using Typescript and use it like OnExeption DriverListener

Tags: typescript, webdriver, webdriver-io

WebdriverIO V8 with JS and TS.

Hello everyone,

I'm currently exploring the afterCommand hook in WebdriverIO to execute a series of actions when specific elements appear in my application. However, I'm encountering challenges with accessing the browser instance or importing the necessary types.

My goal is to utilize the afterCommand hook like the WebDriverEventListener's onException. In my experience with the Selenium framework, I've used onException to manage error messages and handle the closure of randomly generated popups within my test flows.

I would appreciate any guidance or insights on effectively implementing afterCommand for similar scenarios in WebdriverIO V8 with both JavaScript and TypeScript.

Thanks in advance for your help!